# How to display multi day events in drupal calendar view?

Tags: civievent, drupal, drupal-views

I am having a Drupal Calendar view that displaying the Civi Events in month view. But I cannot configure it to display the multi-day events.

I have some multi-day events in Civi Events. But the calendar shows this only in the start date. Not showing it in multi column till the end date.

Please suggest a way to achieve this in drupal view.

And I am using Drupal 7.56 and CiviCRM 4.7.29.

Thank you!

Comment: It may depend on how you set up the drupal view - you could try comparing with the one available for download at https://www.fuzion.co.nz/blogs/simple-view-showing-civi-events-calendar which uses CiviCRM Entities module which opens up more possibilities

Comment: I cannot get this done with drupal View. So I am this module. It works fine.
https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_events